# I am wondering about the DISCONNECT time base of wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, wifi, wpa-supplicant

I am using `wpa_supplicant` and `wpa_cli`.

It is out of signal of connecting AP.

However, `wpa_supplicant` does not directly follow DISCONNECT.

After a few seconds, wpa_supplicant becomes DISCONNET on the AP being connected.

I wonder if it will be DISCONNET in a few seconds after leaving the AP because of some criteria.

※
It seems to be DISCONNECT approximately 30 seconds after the signal is out of range.

Comment: The closest `wpa_supplicant.conf` option I found is `dot11RSNAConfigSATimeout=60` which you could try to change.

Comment: I got the answer. It was not "dot11RSNAConfigSATimeout = 60".

Comment: Then write an answer with it.

Comment: I'm sorry. English is immature. This option has not been resolved.

Comment: What is the option change you had to do?  I don't expect a tutorial, just an option name.

Comment: I looked at the source of wpa_supplicant.
On the source, the value of dot11RSNAConfigSATimeout was 60 by default.(src/ap/wpa_auth.c, src/rsn_supp/wpa.c)
I recompiled it by changing the default value to 10. 
I also set "dot11RSNAConfigSATimeout = 10" in the /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf file.
I expected the time to become DISCONNECT to be reduced. But it was the same.

Comment: `dot11RSNAConfigSATimeout` is for the [RSNA](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11i) protocols (TKIP and CCMP). The "disconnect after out of range" (i.e., signal too low/too bad) timeout is probably implemented in the Linux kernel and/or the WLAN drivers.